# Open the Explorer Process in c#

Tags: c#

I'm currently having a issue i need to create a App that open the Explorer.exe Process after the Credentials are Correct.

What i decided to do was the Following after it searched the DB and the info is correct.

```
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "explorer.exe";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

After the App Opens the CMD but does not start the Explorer Function.

What am i doing Wrong or is there another Way .

Thanks

Comment: What kind of "app" is it?  Winform?  Console? ASP? Service?

Comment: Its in WPF, but im running this in as a Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would try to open Windows Explorer from a new command line process, just start Explorer directly:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //I don't need it, but the OP did.
startInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Verified working on .NET 4.5, Windows 7

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Promt Reply i tried that from a start but i get this Error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables.

im using .NET 4.5, Windows 7

Comment: @JuanAngelArias I ran this code as a program (my main was that code). It ran fine, and opened explorer. That said, I added the requested line and it still worked fine, so go ahead and add it.